# Change reference from GAC to BIN on .net website?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, gac, bin

I added a reference to the third party .net tool Farpoint Spread in my asp.net website. This was an actual install on my machine so the DLL's got installed into my GAC. When I add references to the DLL's they also point to the GAC (even though I copied them to a seperate folder).

What I would like to do is reference the DLL's from a third party DLL folder in my solution and they then get dropped in the BIN (and I would then just check in the .refresh files to TFS). Is there anyway to change the below from GAC to BIN? I am picking the third party folder DLLs however it is referring to the GAC (I am guessing this is visual studio's first place to look before falling back on the BIN).

My goal is not have to have every developer install this Farpoint tool so when they get everything from TFS it is properly references in my third party folder.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to manually add these assemblies to your bin folder.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew%28v=vs.80%29.aspx